# "//" on top of every html page using laravel 5 blade layout

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm creating web application using laravel 5. Everypage has "//" on up-left corner. What is causing this? 
The app.blade.php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Page Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    @yield("content")
    <p>Above content generated by MVC</p> 
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's gonna be in your code. Look for comments outside of the PHP tags. Good practice is also not to close a PHP tag unless explicitly required - and you shouldn't need to anyway with a framework and everything but the startup script in an object, or template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it certainly isn't anything in the blade template that's doing it.

What is probably happening is that you've got somewhere in your code a line which says `echo "//";` or something similar, or a rogue line of code before your `<?php` block starts -- maybe you were trying to comment out a block of code that includes a `<?php` block.

That line doesn't have to be in the template; it could be anywhere in the code; if it's run before the template is output, then you will get the kind of effect that you're reporting here.

As for where the line is and what it's doing there, that's something you'll have to work out for yourself. But you can start by searching your codebase for `echo` or `print` statements, and for `//<?php`.

Comment: It was "//<?php" in routes.php. Thanks!